# Publish question button is disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions, posts

I recently posted a question, but after reviewing the question I noticed the Post Question button is disabled.

I tried to make little changes in the question body without success.

Finally, I edited the HTML in the Developer Tools to enable the button, and posting the question worked. It is an edge case probably, but just reporting it in case you find the problem.

Using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04.

---

Actually, right when trying to publish this very question on Meta, I am seeing the same issue again:

> [image]

---

After entering the question tags I pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the Post Question button is disabled.

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker or script blocker?

Comment: E:NOREPRO.  Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116, Firefox Version 78.0.1 (repos), Chromium Version 83.0.4103.61 snapped, all on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed as discussed at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353280/235711.

This was only happening when you entered the review step using the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, due to a competing `submit` event listener.